# GARCH parameter estimation with only observed volatility

Tags: r, time-series, estimation, matlab, garch

I would like to estimate the parameters of a GARCH process:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&r_t  = \sigma_t\epsilon_t,\\
&\sigma_t^2 = \mu + \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_ir_{t-i}^2 + \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j\sigma_{t-j}^2,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon_t\sim N(0,1)$. The common procedure would be to estimate the parameters $\mu$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, given some observations of $r_t$. However, I am facing a problem in which observations of $\sigma_t$ are available, *but not $r_t$*. In this case, is it possible to estimate the parameters, in particular, with existing packages in R or Matlab?

Comment: I have a feeling this is impossible, but I do not have any proof of that.

Comment: @RichardHardy Hard to tell from the question (OP should definitely add much more relevant detail), but they might be trying to fit a GARCH model to an implied volatility estimate, e.g. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8e81/1b75b32599a02fa2320f9f0e9c8cff69ce12.pdf.

Comment: @tchakravarty, I have skimmed through the paper, but I cannot find where (if) they fit a GARCH model based on volatility estimates instead of returns. Or do you mean that $r_t$ are (or can be understood as) the "volatilities" in the subject-matter sense, so the model is fit as usual and just the subject-matter interpretation is unusual?

Comment: @RichardHardy Pretty much. They fit GARCH models to an IV index called the VXN, which they continue to represent as $r_t$.

Comment: @tchakravarty, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I do not have much more detail to provide. We are trying to build a time series model for a positive quantity. So the positive quantity (i.e. $\sigma$) is observable, but not $r$.

Comment: @KENG, does $\sigma_t$ actually represent an estimate of volatility? If so, let us denote it $\hat\sigma_t$. (You are not observing the actual value of the parameter, are you?) Are you interested specifically in building a GARCH model or just any (appropriate) model for $\sigma_t$ based on measurements $\hat\sigma_t$?

Comment: @Richard Hardy, thanks for your help. The quantity we intend to model is not volatility. We simply find that the Garch model: 1) guarantees positiveness, 2) is commonly used, 3) gives properties, such as clustering, suitable for our needs. Personally, I am curious that why there is almost no paper or discussion on this. It seems to be an interesting reseach topic.

Comment: @KENG GARCH models are routinely applied to non-financial time series such as travel mode demand forecasting or power demand forecasting. You can find plenty of references on Google Scholar.

Comment: If the quantity of interest is not volatility, then GARCH is little likely to be appropriate. After all, it models the latent conditional variance of a time series, while you are dealing with something else. There are other models for positive time series, but I am no expert, so I cannot recommend a concrete one. A very simple approach would be to take a logarithm of your series and model that with ARIMA or the like. @tchakravarty, are the GARCH models you refer to used for something else than modelling time-varying autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity (as intended)?